# Can I use some jQuery editor's plugin in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I know there isn't any powerful editor plugin (just RichTextArea control which requires too much work to be done and is really limited) in Silverlight whereas there are a bunch of editors available in jQuery. Can I use them in my Silverlight application?

I know there is a webbrowser control. But it won't let me have the contents of the editor's textarea so that I can save it to database. It will just give me the whole HTML for the webpage. So this is confusing me because if I directly dump all of the contents the database will keep growing filled with useless HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this free component from VectorLight, [Html RichTextArea](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/controls/html_richtextarea.aspx).